# "SELECT VALUE" - value keyword in LINQ/Entity Framework query

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

What does the keyword "value" mean in this statement, and where would I go to learn more?
What happens if I leave out the keyword "value"? In the code below, z is an entity framework class.

```
string queryString = "SELECT VALUE q from x.zs as q where q.a = @parm;"
ObjectQuery<z> query = context.CreateQuery<z> 
    (queryString, new ObjectParameter("parmname",parmvalue)); 
return query.First();
```

(This is a part of a practice question for an exam).

The above code is in a function that returns a variable of type z.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That is [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738683.aspx) syntax. `Value` keyword allows only one value to be specified, and does not add a row wrapper.

Read [article about SELECT statement in ESQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399554.aspx)

> Entity SQL supports two variants of the SELECT clause. The first
>   variant, row select, is identified by the SELECT keyword, and can be
>   used to specify one or more values that should be projected out.
>   Because a row wrapper is implicitly added around the values returned,
>   the result of the query expression is always a multiset of rows.
>
> Each query expression in a row select must specify an alias. If no
>   alias is specified,Entity SQL attempts to generate an alias by using
>   the alias generation rules.
>
> The other variant of the SELECT clause, value select, is identified by
>   the SELECT VALUE keyword. It allows only one value to be specified,
>   and does not add a row wrapper.

So, if you want to materialize `z` object from your query, you should use `SELECT VALUE` syntax (otherwise you will get exception: cast from MaterializedDataRecord to z type is not valid).

Without `VALUE` keyword you will get set of rows:

```
string esql = "SELECT q from x.zs as q where q.a = @parm;";
ObjectQuery<DbDataRecord> query = context
       .CreateQuery<DbDataRecord>(esql, new ObjectParameter("parm",parmvalue)); 
var result = query.First();
```