# Entity Framework 5, Code First, Full Text Search but IQueryable via CreateQuery?

Tags: ef-code-first, full-text-search, iqueryable, createquery

I am using .NET 4.5 and EF 5 with Code First approach and now I need to implement Full Text Search.
I have already read a lot about it and so far my conclusions are:

- Stored procedures nor Table Value Functions can not be mapped with Code First.
- Still I can call them using dynamic sql

  *dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<Movie>(Sql, parameters)*

But this returns IEnumerable and I want IQueryable so that I can do more filtering before fetching the data from db server. I know I can send those parameters to Db function but I don't want that.

- What I have found that could fulfill my needs is CreateQuery function from IObjectContextAdapter that looks like this(Select All just for test):

  *IQueryable<Movie> result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<Movie>("SELECT * FROM Movie");*
- However executing this throws Exception"
  'System.Data.EntitySqlException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232006
  Message=The query syntax is not valid. Near term '*', line 1, column 9.'

So the questions are:

- Why do I get this exception and can it be fixed ?
- If not is there any way with Code First to do FTS that returns IQueryable ?

Comment: Just to update answer:
My post(at the moment it is the last one) on the following topic:
[a-composable-full-text-search-with-a-code-first-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746127/a-composable-full-text-search-with-a-code-first-model/20744678#20744678)

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this

```
ObjectQuery<Movie> query = 
    objectContext.CreateQuery<Movie>(@"SELECT VALUE movie FROM Movies");
```

As for `why` see these links

> Differences from Transact-SQL Unlike Transact-SQL, Entity SQL does not
>   support use of the * argument in the SELECT clause. Instead

[Entity SQL Reference - SELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399554.aspx)
["SELECT VALUE" - value keyword in LINQ/Entity Framework query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15386766/select-value-value-keyword-in-linq-entity-framework-query)