# Linq select with column name

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to select with column name from table with LINQ
Basically I want select only single column records from a table with Column Name

this is what i have used so far

```
public static IQueryable<T> SelectByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string ColumnName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, ColumnName);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = "Select";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

I am getting following error

**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1'.**

I tried above method with reference to following method

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByField<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, string SortField, bool Ascending)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
        var prop = Expression.Property(param, SortField);
        var exp = Expression.Lambda(prop, param);
        string method = Ascending ? "OrderBy" : "OrderByDescending";
        Type[] types = new Type[] { q.ElementType, exp.Body.Type };
        var mce = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), method, types, q.Expression, exp);
        return q.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(mce);
    }
```

Comment: `DbQuery` does not implement `IQueryable`, just `IEnumerable`. Hence this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746127/a-composable-full-text-search-with-a-code-first-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dynamic library which will allow you to build a dynamic where clause with Linq

check these links:

[Link to install the dynamic library](http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/)

[Scott Gu examples](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

regards