# How to map CONTAINSTABLE function in Entity Framework (code-first)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, full-text-search

Thanks to https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/, it is now possible to map functions in Entity Framework (code-first). I am trying to map [CONTAINSTABLE function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189760.aspx). How can pass the `table` argument?

It might be good to use generic for that:

```
db.ContainsTable<MyEntity>(myTerm)
```

could translate into:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTAINSTABLE(MyEntities, *, @myTerm)
```

Should I somehow use [CreateQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339670%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that?

(There are some older tries: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746127/a-composable-full-text-search-with-a-code-first-model) and hacky [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644900/121968). But with EF 6.1 and CF functions I am trying to find something more clean.)

Comment: Did you find a nice solution in the end?

Comment: @Gavin Some hints, but not tried yet: https://codefirstfunctions.codeplex.com/discussions/541844

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataTable for it.

1. Create 'DataTable' var dt=new DataTable()
2. Create Columns and Rows ot table
3. Create Parameter

   ```
   var dtparameter = new SqlParameter("paramname", SqlDbType.Structured);
   dtparameter.Value= dt;
   dtparameter.TypeName = "dbo.udt_tableName";
   ```

Pass this parameter to entity framework for calling tablevalue parameter.

Comment: You mean this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx `DataTable`? How use this in LINQ in the Entity Framework?